# How can I call multiple remote services from an activity

Tags: android, android-activity, service, onserviceconnected

How can I call multiple remote services from an activity? It seems that you can only have one onServiceConnected() in an activity? Can onServiceConnected() connect to multiple remote services at the same time?

Comment: Binding to a service directly from an activity has been an anti-pattern for a decade, as it does not deal with configuration changes. Use a repository, viewmodel, retained fragment, or something else that survives configuration changes. Beyond that, though, you can create different `ServiceConnection` objects, one per service.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. What configuration changes? Can different ServiceConnection objects connect to one onServiceConnected() and how do I do this? Android Studio does not allow two onServiceConnected() in the one Activity

Comment: "What configuration changes?" -- see [the documentation on configuration changes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes) to learn what they are. "Android Studio does not allow two onServiceConnected() in the one Activity" -- yes, it does. `ServiceConnection` is a Java interface. You can create more than one instance of `ServiceConnection`, just as you can create more than one instance of `View.OnClickListener`.